# React rendering content before props is properly mapped / set

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've created a component with React using Redux where it takes two renders before the state is mapped to the props.

with this code,

'user.private' on first render is null and on the second render, it's false

because of that, loading the page flickers between showing 'login' for a second before showing hidden content

I'd like to show the login text by default, but I don't actually want it to display if the user's private field is set to false.

```
class Content extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { user } = this.props;

        let show = false;

        if (user.private === false) show = true

        return (
            <section>
            {
                show
                ? <p>hidden content</p>  
                : <p>login</p>
            }
            </section>  
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.store.user
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Content)
```

Comment: `if (!user.private) show = true` ?

Comment: that creates the same effect

Answer (score 2):

You can use switch to handle the null case (you can either show a loader or just render nothing by returning null)
I am using the component state to illustrate the idea, but you can apply it to your redux connected Component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user : {
      private : null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState(() => {
          return {
            user : {
              private : true
            }
          }
        });
      }, 2000);
  }

  renderContent () {
    const { user } = this.state;
    switch (user.private) {
      case null : return <span>Loading...</span>
      case false : return <p>login</p> 
      default : return <p>hidden content</p> 
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
          {this.renderContent()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

[demo](https://jsbin.com/dorafiluse/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

Assumming `user` is initially undefined or null, you can check if `user` and/or its property `private` is defined before showing anything:

```
if (this.props.user == null || this.props.user.private) {
  show = false;
}
```

The `double equals null` will make the condition `true` if the value of `this.props.user` is undefined or null. You could also have used `!this.props.user`.

In case you made your initial value for `user` be `{}` even before getting it, then you would have to do:

```
if (this.props.user.private == null || this.props.user.private) {
  show = false;
}
```